# ¿Como conectarse a BBPOS?

Tags: android, ios, sdk

recientemente he querido comenzar un pequeño proyecto, donde tengo un dispositivo BBPOS CHIPPER CHB10

No encuentro ninguna guía, ni SDK para conectarme al equipo y así poder obtener las lecturas de las tarjetas. Cabe mencionar que no tengo mucha experiencia en el tema y ando experimentando un poco.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba creando una cuenta en la pagina:

https://developer.bbpos.com/?returnTo=https://developer.bbpos.com/docs/sdk/bbdevice/integration-guide/transaction/data-encryption/

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/382818)